# Error log PythonAnywhereDjango Python PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Why does hosting on pythonanywhere not work? The syntax seems to me to be correct? Everything works fine on my computer.

http://fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/fixitcemes/files/var/log/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com.error.log

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    """Model representing a device."""
    type_name = models.ManyToManyField(DeviceType, help_text='Select a device type')
    device_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    short_name_device_own = ForeignKey(DeviceType, related_name='device_type_device', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                       null=True)
    prod_year = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    worked_science = models.DateField(auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.short_name_device_own} - {self.device_id}'
```

error log:

```
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,509: Error running WSGI application
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,510:   File "/home/fixitcemes/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/mysite/dokumenty/models.py", line 38
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,510:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511:     return f'{self.short_name_device_own} - {self.device_id}'
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511:                                                             ^
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,511:   File "/var/www/fixitcemes_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:     application = get_wsgi_application()
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:   File "/home/fixitcemes/.virtualenvs/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,512:   File "/home/fixitcemes/.virtualenvs/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,513:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,513:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,513:   File "/home/fixitcemes/.virtualenvs/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,513:     app_config.import_models()
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,514:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,514:   File "/home/fixitcemes/.virtualenvs/fixitcemes.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,514:     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,514: ***************************************************
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,514: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,515: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
    2019-10-13 10:05:37,515: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
```

Comment: You need to set it up following the tutorial - https://www.pythonanywhere.com/details/django_hosting

Comment: f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. You are running Python 3.5.

Comment: @HenryM are you sure? i can see only plans to choice, i have "haker" but still i can see plans only ... no more...

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank You so much!